# Sublist creation by string pattern

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {1, {"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}, {"BC", 7}};
```

...and I would like to make a new list consisting of all elements of lis that begin with "AB", to make:

```
res = {{"AB",2,3},{"ABC",8,9}}
```

This would seem to be a job for SequenceCases, but am not sure how to construct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am sure there are many ways to do this. How about using `Cases` ?

```
lis = {1, {"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}, {"BC", 7}};
Cases[lis, x_ /; (Head[x] === List && StringStartsQ[First@x, "AB"])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
Cases[{_String?(StringMatchQ["AB*"]), ___}] @ lis
```

> ```
> {{"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

```
lis = {1, {"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}, {"BC", 7}};

Select[ListQ@# && StringStartsQ[First@#, "AB"] &][#] &@lis
```

> {{"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}}

---

**ORIGINAL**

As a test case, I have added an entry at the end:

```
lis = {1, {"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}, {"BC", 7}, {4, "CA"}};
```

Select lists: (Not necessary but for demo)

```
f = Cases[#, _List] &
```

Select lists with first `String` element (This takes care of the element being a list too)

```
g = Cases[#, {k_String, x___}] &
```

First element (which is String) matches a pattern:

```
h[x_List] := Pick[x, StringMatchQ[First@x, "AB" ~~ ___]]
```

Execute:

```
h /@ g @ f@ lis
```

OR:

```
Composition[Map[h, #] &, g, f][lis]
```

OR:

```
h /@ g @* f @ lis
```

> {{"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}}

Comment: `Select[ListQ@# && StringStartsQ[First@#, "AB"] &]@lis` works, `f[#]& @x` vs `f@x`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, {"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}, {"BC", 7}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
split = SequenceSplit[list, {{x_, __} /; StringTake[x, 2] != "AB"}]
```

{{1, {"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}}}

```
Cases[split, {_String, __}, -1]
```

{{"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}}

Answer (score 2):

```
lis = {1, {"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}, {"BC", 7}};
```

---

Using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[lis, Except[{str_ /; StringStartsQ[str, "AB"], __} ..]]

(*{{"AB", 2, 3}, {"ABC", 8, 9}}*)
```